# Python KeyError: for x_col value in flow_from_dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, tensorflow, keyerror, image-classification

I have a dataset in which image files are given separately and label for that image files given in separate csv file with 1st column as the image file name and 2nd column its respective label.
My code is below.

```
import pandas as pd
train= pd.read_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab_Notebooks/label_train.csv',dtype=str)
train.head()

number;label
0   101.jpg;3
1   102.jpg;1
2   103.jpg;3
3   104.jpg;3
4   105.jpg;2

test = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab_Notebooks/label_test.csv',dtype=str)
test.head()

number;label
0   201.jpg;3
1   202.jpg;3
2   203.jpg;1
3   204.jpg;3
4   205.jpg;3

train_folder = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab_Notebooks/bilder_train'
test_folder = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab_Notebooks/bilder_test'

import os
import numpy as np
import glob
import shutil
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Conv2D, Flatten, Dropout, MaxPooling2D, BatchNormalization
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras import regularizers, optimizers

train_gen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255, 
                               rotation_range=45, 
                               width_shift_range=.15, 
                               height_shift_range=.15, 
                               horizontal_flip=True, 
                               zoom_range=0.5)
test_gen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_data = train_gen.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe = train, 
                                           directory = train_folder, 
                                           x_col = 'number', 
                                           y_col = 'label', 
                                           seed = 42, 
                                           batch_size = 10, 
                                           shuffle = True, 
                                           class_mode='categorical',
                                           target_size = (100, 100))

test_data = test_gen.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe = test, 
                                         directory = test_folder, 
                                         x_col = 'number', 
                                         y_col = None, 
                                         seed = 42, 
                                         batch_size = 10, 
                                         shuffle = False, 
                                         class_mode='categorical', 
                                         target_size = (100, 100))
```

This is the Error message

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2897             try:
-> 2898                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   2899             except KeyError as err:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'number'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
6 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2898                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   2899             except KeyError as err:
-> 2900                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   2901 
   2902         if tolerance is not None:

KeyError: 'number'
```

I have absolutly no idea why this error occurs. Does anybody know what is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `sep=;` (CSV delimiter) add the end of your `pd.read_csv` function. Since it default `sep` value is `,` so it will interpret `number;label` as a single column instead of 2 separate ones

```
import pandas as pd
train= pd.read_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab_Notebooks/label_train.csv',dtype=str, sep=';')
train.head()

test = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab_Notebooks/label_test.csv',dtype=str, sep=';')
test.head()
```